# build all Spring Boot apps docker(OCI) images with Spring Boot Maven Plugin in one multi-module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have maven multi module project, where most modules are Spring Boot application,
and some `common` modules that are shared between Spring apps.

```xml
     <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>D</module>
    </modules>
```

Now when I want to build docker(OCI) images for Spring apps with `spring-boot:build-image`, like

```
mvn --projects A,B,D --also-make clean install org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image
```

maven still runs `build-image` goal for every `common` modules, that is overkill:
those `common` modules should be built and consumed as jars.

(plugin goal must be in long form like `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image` because on root (parent) level no spring-boot plugin is defined).

**How to build all Spring Boot apps from the project in one `mvn` line, not one by one?**

---

Of course every Spring Boot app module has spring-boot-maven-plugin plugin defined and configured as described on https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using-import

> 3.2. Using Spring Boot without the Parent POM

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Only applu the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to projects that should be runnable jars, else don't apply it.

Comment: So it is. That is why calling plugin goal must be in long form like org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image because on root (parent) level no spring-boot is defined, so maven would tell than "spring-boot" is unknown. Common modules does not depend on spring.

Comment: If you have defined the spring boot plugin in the parent project it will be applied to all modules using that parent.

Comment: I put (plugin goal must be in long form like `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.4:build-image` because on root (parent) level no spring-boot plugin is defined). into Question so it is clear, that parent is without spring-boot plugin

Comment: If the plugin is defined in the projects it will be applied as well, if not the plugin won't be applied.

Answer (score 4):

It seems impossible to do in one command,
so have to

```
mvn clean install
mvn --projects A spring-boot:build-image
mvn --projects B spring-boot:build-image
mvn --projects D spring-boot:build-image
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround:

- Declare the spring-boot plugin in the dependency management section of your parent pom
- Explicitly skip the plugin execution in your common submodules:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

- Execute the plugin for your submodule: `mvn --projects A,B,D --also-make clean install spring-boot:build-image`